# Coefficient matching for GARCH model and R-program output

Tags: r, time-series, coefficients

I have the following output for my garch model using R-program.

```
 Call:
 garch(x = cyber3, order = c(1, 1))

 Model:
 GARCH(1,1)

 Residuals:
       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
 -13.77455  -0.35905   0.07161   0.49866   9.55536 

 Coefficient(s):
     Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
 a0 2.610e-06   1.076e-07    24.25   <2e-16 ***
 a1 1.564e-01   4.098e-03    38.17   <2e-16 ***
 b1 8.460e-01   3.936e-03   214.94   <2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Diagnostic Tests:
         Jarque Bera Test

 data:  Residuals
 X-squared = 160230, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16


         Box-Ljung test

 data:  Squared.Residuals
 X-squared = 0.01052, df = 1, p-value = 0.9183
```

Then just to be safe and confirm, may I know how the a0, a1 and b1 correspond to the actual GARCH mathematical formula? For my guess, they should be constant, coefficient for the past return and coefficient for the past variance if I am correct. May I confirm this?

Comment: Take a look at the `?garch`. Not sure which package you are using but it would be surprising if the function returns something else than the coefficents described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity). (\omega = a0, \alpha_1 = a1 and \beta_1 = b1)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, what helped me was the cited reference paper which led me to the formula that corresponds to these a0, a1 and b1. The baseline is, my inference was correct.